# Click on GML track in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers

How can the click event on a GML track be caught in Open Layers?

I have the following code:

```
var gmlTrack = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("Track", myGpxUrl, {
    format: OpenLayers.Format.GPX,
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

I thought that the solution would be to add the following lines:

```
gmlTrack.events.register("click", gmlTrack, function(e){
    alert("Click on GPX track!");
});
```

But it doesn't work.

To be clear: I only want the click event to be triggered when the user clicks on the GPX track.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for using a select feature control (which enables OpenLayers to know how to handle the events)

```
    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
        [gmlTrack],
        {
            clickout: true, toggle: false,
            multiple: false, hover: false,
            onSelect: trackSelected
        }
    );

    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
```

And include some handler for trackSelected e.g.

```
function trackSelected(feature){
    alert("something here");  
}
```

This is a useful [OpenLayers example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem in my case was caused by the fact that I was using two SelectFeature(s) and it seems that OpenLayers doesn't quite support this. If I deactivate the first SelectFeature the second one will work.

Comment: You definitely can have two select feature controls on the same map, many of my maps do.  You possibly can't have them both active at the same time (which I have never had a case where I wanted that to happen).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: I can't have both active at the same time. I wanted to have one that gets the "hover" event and one that gets the "click" event.